# How to make after-save-hook be invoked on autosave?

Tags: emacs, save, elisp, hook, autosave

I've defined an after-save-hook, and it works great if I save by pressing Ctrl-x Ctrl-s. However, I've noticed that saves triggered pretty much any other way don't trip the hook as expected. First I noticed code that called save-some-buffers didn't trigger it, so I did this:

```
(defadvice save-some-buffers (after after-save-some-buffers activate)
  (run-hooks 'after-save-hook))
```

And that almost worked except it would run the hook even if the file hadn't changed, so it still wasn't ideal. But then I noticed autosaving didn't trigger it either. So I consulted the docs and found the do-auto-save function and tried the same trick:

```
(defadvice do-auto-save (after after-auto-save activate)
  (run-hooks 'after-save-hook))
```

And there the hook doesn't execute at all. do-auto-save is a C source function so presumably it doesn't invoke whatever elisp would normally trigger the hook.

In short how do I make it so whenever emacs saves my modified buffers that after-save-hook actually runs?

Comment: Could you give us a hint of why you need to run code after auto-save?  A direct answer to your question might not exist, so it's useful to provide extra info about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`after-save-hook` runs when executing `save-some-buffers`.  It would be very strange if it didn't.  Can you create a repro from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem. I want to remove trailing space on save but   `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)` is not triggered with `auto-save`.